# Looping over one pandas column to match values with index of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

`Exp` is one `DataFrame` with `datetime` `object`

```
           Exp
0   1989-06-01
1   1989-07-01
2   1989-08-01
3   1989-09-01
4   1989-10-01
```

`CL` is the `Dataframe` with `Index` as `DateTime Object`

```
                    CL
1989-06-01   68.800026
1989-06-04   68.620026
1989-06-05   68.930023
1989-06-06   68.990021
1989-06-09   69.110023
```

- I want to add new column `R` into `CL` dataframe which have will have date from Exp matching with `CL` Index.

This what my desired output should look like

```
                   CL          R

1989-06-01   68.800026   1989-06-01
1989-06-04   68.620026
1989-06-05   68.930023
1989-06-06   68.990021
1989-06-09   69.110023
```

This is what I tried doing:

```
for m in Exp.iloc[:,0]:
if m == CL.index:
    CL['R'] = m
```

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Can someone please help me ? I keep getting this ValueError a lot of times

Comment: The error is because you're comparing a scalar `m` to an array `CL.index` which has many values. Test that statement in your interpreter -- what it will return will be an array of boolean values as long as the index. The error is telling you that you need to evaluate the array as a single value; so use `any()` if even one `True` in the array should be counted as true, or `all()` if all values in the array must be true.

Comment: Besides the error, the assignment `CL['Exp'] = m` will overwrite the any existing `CL['Exp']` value on each match it produces, since you're assigning a scalar `m` to a the column `Exp`. The result you're looking for can be thought of as a SQL left join -- read up on either pandas.DataFrame.merge or pandas.DataFrame.join to see how you can perform a left join-like operation in pandas.

Comment: I want to pick one value of m and search in the CL.Index array if it exists there. if it does I want to add a row of that date into new column of R for that same date.

Comment: I changed the code a little bit it should be  CL['R'] = m. I want to create a new column in CL named R

Comment: Can i do this by Apply method? or some other sophisticated way ?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: updated with commenters suggestion.

You need to do LEFT JOIN:

```
Exp = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.to_datetime(['1989-06-01', '1989-07-01', '1989-08-01', '1989-09-01', '1989-10-01']),
    columns=['Exp'])
```

gives:

```
          Exp
0  1989-06-01
1  1989-07-01
2  1989-08-01
3  1989-09-01
4  1989-10-01
```

and

```
CL = pd.DataFrame(
[68.800026, 68.620026, 68.930023, 68.990021, 69.110023],
index = pd.to_datetime(['1989-06-01', '1989-06-04', '1989-06-05', '1989-06-06', '1989-06-09']),
columns = ['CL'])
```

gives

```
                   CL
1989-06-01  68.800026
1989-06-04  68.620026
1989-06-05  68.930023
1989-06-06  68.990021
1989-06-09  69.110023
```

then:

```
(CL
 .reset_index()
 .merge(Exp, how='left', right_on='Exp', left_on='index')
 .set_index('index')
 .rename(columns={'Exp': 'R'}))
```

returns what you are looking for

```
                   CL           R
index                            
1989-06-01  68.800026  1989-06-01
1989-06-04  68.620026         NaN
1989-06-05  68.930023         NaN
1989-06-06  68.990021         NaN
1989-06-09  69.110023         NaN
```

Because looping over dataframe is not Pandas way of doing things.

Comment: `R` has `NaN` because you didn't set the columns/index to `Timestamps`.... Other than that, looks good!  PlusOne.

Comment: @piRSquared, updated according to your suggestions! I must have overlooked that those are `Datetime` columns.

Answer (score 0):

**[`pd.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)**
`join` focuses on combining dataframes/series via the index.
Use `set_index` on `Exp` with `drop=False` to keep the same information in the dataframe proper and the index.  We put it in the index to make `join` convenient.

```
CL.join(Exp.set_index('Exp', drop=False)).rename(columns=dict(Exp='R'))

                   CL          R
1989-06-01  68.800026 1989-06-01
1989-06-04  68.620026        NaT
1989-06-05  68.930023        NaT
1989-06-06  68.990021        NaT
1989-06-09  69.110023        NaT
```

---

**Setup**

```
Exp = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Exp=pd.to_datetime(
            ['1989-06-01', '1989-07-01', '1989-08-01', '1989-09-01', '1989-10-01'])
    ))

CL = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        CL=[68.800026, 68.620026, 68.930023, 68.990021, 69.110023],
    ), pd.to_datetime(
        ['1989-06-01', '1989-06-04', '1989-06-05', '1989-06-06', '1989-06-09']))
```